# Proving that if $m,n,p,q\in\mathbb{Z^+}, \sqrt[p]{m}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt[p]{m}+\sqrt[q]{n}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

If $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt[q]{n}=r$ rational, the rationality of $\sqrt{m}$ is derived expanding $(r-\sqrt{m})^q$ using the binomial theorem: after rearrangement, isolating the terms containing odd powers of $\sqrt{m}$ and factoring it out, we're done.

A similar trick does not work for the more general case stated in the title. Is it provable by elementary means?

Comment: In general, it does not seem to be true in its current form: take $p=q$ both odd, and take $n=-m$. Now the sum gives $0$, which is rational.

Comment: @WillR: $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Comment: Well, you may still compute the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+\beta$, given the minimal polynomial $x^p-m$ of $\alpha$ and the minimal polynomial $x^q-n$ of $\beta$, then apply the rational root theorem.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I know the theorem, but how do I compute the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+\beta$ from those of the individual summands? Is there a formula or something? Sorry if it's trivial.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: represent the powers $(x+y)^h$, for $0\leq h \leq pq$, with respect to a base of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^p-m,y^q-n)$ and perform gaussian elimination. That gives a polynomial $\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that vanishes at $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Got it, thank you!